# Where is the verb between "as" and "unless" in this example?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, passive-voice

Mother:
- On no account should you take my credit card it for shopping!

Ann:
-Take it easy mum,as credit card holder unless you sign for me,l cannot use your card anyhow.

Comment: Also "... *it* for shoping" looks wrong.

Comment: Cardinal is right: The "it" is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

There is no verb; "as" in this usage is a preposition, the head of a prepositional phrase which modifies a noun, although there are several other problems with your sentence.

The noun being modified by the prepositional phrase in the example you gave is "I" but, from context, it should be "mum" or "you" (implying the mum is the credit card holder).

The phrase "unless you sign for me" is also misplaced; it belongs next to the main clause, not within the prepositional phrase.

**Unless you, as credit card holder, sign for me, I cannot use your card anyhow.**

Answer (score 1):

> *Take it easy mum, **as credit card holder**, unless you sign for me, l*
>   *cannot use your card anyhow*.

"As credit card holder" is a PP where the head "as" has had its clausal complement reduced to just the noun phrase "credit card holder". The subject pronoun of the clause, as well as the auxiliary verb and the determiner have all been ellipted (omitted).

If we fill out the ellipsis, we get "as you are the credit card holder". The PP serves an adjunct of reason. Incidentally, I would replace the comma after "mum" with a dash or a semicolon, or even a full stop followed by a new sentence.

Comment: If ***I*** fill out the ellipsis, I get "you **being / who are / in the capacity of** the credit card holder". Any of which I'd prefer to see immediately *after* the referent *(**you**)*, otherwise I can't help thinking of "dangling participles".

Comment: An alternative analysis might be to treat "as credit card holder" as a predicative adjunct, with "you" as predicand.

Comment: I don't think the location of the adjunct "unless you sign for me" matters too much. If we fill out the ellipsis, the prep "as" should be retained, otherwise we are not so much filling out the ellipsis, as replacing the PP with a clause/different category of phrase.

Comment: To my eye the sentence you have given here is still incorrect. The ellipsis only appears to work because we [think we] know what it's *supposed* to say. What if the sentence was instead, "Take it easy mum, as a minor, unless you sign for me, I cannot use your card anyhow."?

Comment: For me the problem is that the first half wants the 'alternative analysis' but the second half wants the original analysis. It should be *as credit card holder, you need to sign, or else I can't use the card* or *you're the credit card holder, so unless you sign for me, I can't use your card anyhow*.